# How to display specific field using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a  `PersonVO` object having fields `firstname`, `lastname`, `id`.

I am preparing an `Arraylist` of `PersonVO` objects in backend with the help of Json API, and I want to display it in frontend with the help of jQuery.

How to display only specific fields without hard-coding the fields in frontend like `this.firstname` or `this.id` or `this.lastname`, possibly hiding the `id` field?

Comment: Please tidy up the formatting/spelling of your question, and take a read of [Stack Overflow's Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: What do you mean by "displaying" the field?

Comment: @Alex, thanks; I tried myself, but...it didn't seem to make much sense to me even after I tried. Certainly not without information about the 'GSON' response, or the jQuery script (as a **minimum**)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to traverse through all object properties.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/u78Ce/

Edit: I think you meant to save the keys somewhere in your program, and later access that key of an Object. In javascript, for objects, a.var is the same as a['var']. So you could do something like

```
var first_name_column = 'firstName', last_name_column = 'secondName';
```

Then later in your code, access them like

```
var person = { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" }; 
var fn = person[first_name_column], ln = person[last_name_column];
```

Comment: var p = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    id: "2"
};

$.each(p, function(key, value) {
     document.write(key + " " + value + "<br/>");
}); exactly like this ,but i dont want all the fileds to display,i have to dislay only  secific fields,is there any way to define inclusion of keys with jquery or json.

Comment: But Still it is hardcoding of values,i want to exclude fields from json data using Gson API.Instead of jquery traversing all the object each time.